# addEventListener('click) not triggering when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

Goal: Clicking on the button opens a link in a new page.
Issue: eventListener not triggering when button is clicked

setTimeout is used to load content after DOM is loaded. DOMContentLoaded does not work with Odoo (the CRM I am writing this script for).
Button element:

```
<button type="button" class="btn oe_stat_button o_field_widget o_readonly_modifier"></button>
```

Event listener:

```
const mainButton = document.querySelector('.btn.oe_stat_button.o_field_widget.o_readonly_modifier');
mainButton.addEventListener('click', () => window.open(linkConfig,'_blank'));
```

I have verified that my button is well assigned to the mainButton and found in the DOM.
I have verified that the value assigned to container is found in the DOM.

```js
if (window.location.href.includes('&menu_id=307')) {
    setTimeout(linkToSupplier, 3000);

}

function linkToSupplier() {

    const container = document.querySelector('[data-id^="product.supplierinfo_"]').innerText;
    const supplierContent = document.querySelector('[title="Supplier"]');

    function linkConfig(supplierLink) {

        supplierContent.innerText = '';
        const link = document.createElement("a")

        // Create txt
        const txt = document.createTextNode("Vist Website ")

        //append txt to anchor element
        link.appendChild(txt)

        // set the innerText
        link.title = "Visit Website ";
        link.target = 'target="_blank"';

        // set the href property
        link.href = supplierLink;

        // get text to add link to
        const mainButton = document.querySelector('.btn.oe_stat_button.o_field_widget.o_readonly_modifier');
        mainButton.outerHTML = `<button type="button" class="btn oe_stat_button o_field_widget o_readonly_modifier"></button>`;
        mainButton.addEventListener('click', () => window.open(supplierLink, '_blank'));
        const purchase = supplierContent;
        purchase.prepend(link);
    }

    window.addEventListener('hashchange', () => setTimeout(linkToSupplier, 1000));

    if (container.includes('All Care')) {
        linkConfig('https://www.all-care.eu/');
    }

}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn oe_stat_button o_field_widget o_readonly_modifier" name="is_published" aria-label="Unpublished" title="Unpublished">
   <i class="fa fa-fw o_button_icon fa-globe text-danger"></i>
   <div class="o_stat_info">
      <span class="o_stat_text">Go to<br>Website</span>
   </div>
</button>
```

Comment: What's this all about `setTimeout(linkToSupplier, 3000);` - are you trying to wait an arbitrary amount of time hoping something is available in the DOM? There's an event for that `DOMContentLoaded`

Comment: You want to open `linkConfig`?  don't you mean  `supplierLink`?

Comment: Can you update this to a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Also is this a typo?? `window.open(linkConfig,'_blank'))` - the _method_ is called `linkConfig` --- did you mean `supplierLink` which is the argument?

Comment: Also add your full HTML markup. Hard to guess your issue.

Comment: Yes this was a typo on the post, I have rectified it.
It does not solve the problem.

Comment: @Jamiec I am developping a script for a CRM called Odoo.
I have to load content after page init but DOMContentLoaded does not work.

Comment: @ben: Perhaps that 3rd party tool offers a way to integrate the functionality?  Because waiting an arbitrary amount of time for an asynchronous operation to complete also doesn't "work", it only "sometimes coincidentally works".  (Though this may be an entirely separate issue from the question being asked...)

Comment: @EzraSiton It is bloated code generated by a CRM. Not convinced it would help and won't be clearly readable.

Comment: @David I agree but I don't have access to the dev environment of the CRM. 
I have tested the timeout so that the script always loads on time.

Comment: @Jamiec I can see the modifications of the mainButton outerHTML upon loading of the DOM. That should mean the script is executed right?

Comment: @ben: *"Not convinced it would help"* - Being able to demonstrate the problem is very likely to help in correcting the problem.  How have you confirmed that the code shown is specifically the problem?  What debugging have you done on this specific code?  If this code isn't the actual code you're using and only kind of looks like the code you're using, how useful is it at all?

Comment: Having said this is unanswerable I think I just spotted the problem!

Comment: BTW, see my answer for how you could have provided a [mcve] to demonstrate the problem without having to show loads of HTML/irrelevant code. I think perhaps you would have worked out the answer if you had tried to isolate the problem like this - but hey thats the art of debugging/programming.

Comment: @Jamiec I understand. Never knew that using the outerHTML method loses the identifier.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get a reference to a DOM element, but then replace its `outerHTML`, you no longer have a reference to the DOM element, it is a new element entirely.

You'd expect the below to work. It doesn't, just like your code.

```js
const mainButton = document.querySelector('.btn');
mainButton.outerHTML = `<button type="button" class="btn">foo</button>`;
mainButton.addEventListener('click', () => console.log("Clicked"));
```

```html
<div class="btn">MyButton</div>
```

What you need to do is get a new reference to the new element.

```js
const mainButton = document.querySelector('.btn');
mainButton.outerHTML = `<button type="button" class="btn">foo</button>`;
const newButton = document.querySelector('.btn');
newButton.addEventListener('click', () => console.log("Clicked"));
```

```html
<div class="btn">MyButton</div>
```